# How to retain GIF frame order in Photoshop when creating an animated GIF?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animated-gif, frame

So I have a GIF that has 70 frames on Photoshop. I put all that into a group (70 images) and it works fine when I press the play button. But when I try to duplicate this folder, the copy doesn't have the order…

Like instead of displaying image 1 at frame 1 and image 2 at frame 2 it just displays every image at all frames.

Is there a way to retain the frame order?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found a solution, I just had to convert the GIF into a video montage with the button on the bottom left, then I was able to duplicate the GIF several times and crop out what I wanted to use… Here’s my result:

[image: Animated GIF]